# scripts on Cshell

Tags: programming-languages, scripting, csh, tcsh

I've got some problem, I have list of data in the file:

```
053-37878 03828008 Moskovitch James 500
052-34363 01234567 Mendelson Kippi 450
053-32322 03828008 Jameson Shula 350
054-39238 03333333 Merden Moshe 300
```

is it possible rewrite this list in the same file (without using temporary file) but without last number thanks in advance for any help (I'm talking about C-Shell scripts)

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: sorry, what does it mean?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have an attempt at making it work which fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why do you need to avoid temporary files?

   ```
   cut -d " " -f 1,2,3 myfile > myfile2; mv myfile2 myfile
   ```
2. You can also easily use Perl's `-i` switch to edit the file in place. It still creates a temp file under the covers, IIRC.
3. If you need this for homework, use Perl to read the file into memory (File::Slurp), chop off last field using regex or somesuch; and write over the file from entire stored data using another File::Slurp

Comment: This is broken and dangerous!  The clobbering from the `> myfile` happens *before* `cut` can read from it, and so this will simply delete the contents of `myfile`!  It's an easy mistake to make, and this is *fine* if you have `cut -d " " -f 1,2,3 my-in-file > my-out-file`.

Comment: @Antal S-Z: I need to work with the same file (no temporary files) is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: lego69: Why?  DVK is right—it's an odd requirement.  And their first answer seems like the best one to me (especially since Perl is just creating a temp file too.)

Comment: its my homework, I'm trying to undrstand how can I solve this problem, but I'm stuck with this requirement!